# How to write a C++ backend for Ubuntu Touch that can access internet?

Tags: application-development, internet, c++, ubuntu-sdk

Is there anyway to write a C++ backend for an Ubuntu Touch application that can access the internet, and download files?

Or do I have to do that through QML, and pass it to objects written in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to access the Internet on the C++ side by using something standard like sockets or `libcurl` that is installed by default.

Oh, I've forgotten the obvious one: the Qt library has networking classes.

Look at network examples that come with Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-network.html

"HTTP Example" is about downloading a file using `QNetworkRequest`.

### CMake and Qt5

The most recent CMake syntax for enabling Qt5 modules is:

```
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)

...

target_link_libraries(my-binary Qt5::Network)
```

The name of the binary is the name of the file into which your cpp files will be compiled: an executable (in the case of a C++ project) or a library (in the case of QML project with C++ plugin).

The binaries are defined in CMake with command `add_executable` or `add_library`. So search for that and link Qt5::Network after the binary is defined.

Comment: So I've been reading through the libcurl tutorial at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html. However, in regards to building, where are the libcurl headers located?? How should I modify my "includes" in my .cpp and .h files? Do I need to make any changes to my CMakeLists.txt???

Comment: My bad, I totally forgot about the networking that is in Qt itself.

Comment: Where am I mean't to add the line:
'target_link_libraries(my-binary Qt5::Network)' ??

and how do I find the name of 'my-binary' ? Thanks.

Comment: I found the line: `add_library(WhereATbackend MODULE ${WhereATbackend_SRCS} )`

So I added: `target_link_libraries(WhereATbackend Qt5::Network)` after.

However I'm getting an error: `/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:27: error: The imported target "Qt5::Core" references the file "/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/moc" but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include: * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location. * An install or u`...

Comment: I forgot to run cmake again, sorry. It's working now :)